# Play Raw VP8 video frames

Tags: video, udp, gstreamer, voip, rtp

I am new in voip and I am currently playing with rtp and srtp .I am building a proxy which convert srtp stream to rtp.I have converted the SRTP to RTP and save the payload to files(.txt format) 1 for audio and 2nd for video.I can play the audio file using audacity but how can I play video file from the 2nd video file which is in VP8 codec .

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was Able to play my converted rtp VP8 frames using GStreamer using following command .

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe  -m -vvv filesrc location="-" ! pcapparse !application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=VP8, encoding-name=VP8-DRAFT-IETF-01 ,framerate=(fraction)20/1 ! rtpvp8depay !  vp8dec !  identity drop-probability=0.1  ! autovideosink sync=false async=false
```

Comment: can we save the output to an mp4 file?